# pcolormesh use of memory

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been struggling with this for a while. I have a set of images, I perform some math on the X, Y coordinates of these images and then plot the new images using pcolormesh. All the calculations I've already done, all I do is load the new X's and new Y's and use the colors from the image in pcolormesh.

The images are 2048x2448 pixels (say approx 5mp), first image goes pretty fast and every image after that the script gets slower and eats more memory. I have tried some garbage collection but it doesn't work.

My script:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cPickle as pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

# TRY forced garbage collection!
import gc

def rectify(cam_files, cam_rec_files, rec_file_location):
    ''' cam_files is a dictionary that contains the filenames with the camera-names as index
            example: {'KDXX04C' : C:\Users\Yorian\Desktop\TU\Stage Shore\python_files\Rectify, metadata and upload\v3\archive\KDXXXXX\original\snap\1381383000\{filename}.jpg }

        cam_rec_files_dir contains a dictionary, cameraName : fileLocation
            example: {'KDXX04C' : C:\Users\Yorian\Desktop\TU\Stage Shore\python_files\Rectify, metadata and upload\v3\camdata\KDXXXXX\KDXX04C.pkl }

        rec_file_location is a string that shows where the new rectification needs to be saved '''
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(60,90))

    for camname in cam_files:
        img = Image.open(cam_files[camname])
        img = np.asarray(img, dtype=np.uint8)
        height, width, channels = img.shape

        # load plot data
        fh = open(cam_rec_files[camname], 'rb')
        X = pickle.load(fh)
        Y = pickle.load(fh)

        masks = [X<=0, X>1500, Y>4000, Y<-4000]
        total_mask = masks[0] | masks[1] | masks[2] | masks[3]
        first_false = np.argwhere(total_mask == 0)
        start = int(first_false[0]/width)

        rgb = img.reshape((-1,3))/255.0
        rgba = np.concatenate((rgb, np.ones((rgb.shape[0],1), dtype=np.uint8)), axis=1)
        rgba[total_mask,3] = 0
        rgba = rgba.reshape((height,width,4))[:,:-1,:]
        rgba = rgba.reshape((-1,4))

        plotimg = ax.pcolormesh(X.reshape((height, width))[start:,:], Y.reshape((height, width))[start:,:], img.mean(-1)[start:,:], cmap='Greys') # img.mean(-1)

        plotimg.set_array(None)
        plotimg.set_edgecolor('none')
        plotimg.set_facecolor(rgba[(start*(width-1)):,:])

        fh.close()

    plt.savefig(rec_file_location)
    gc.collect()
```

It works until six images, but when I try eight for example I have insufficient memory (I use python 64bit and have 12gb of memory on my computer which I imagined to be enough).

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, call `plt.close(fig)` when you're through with it if you're using the `pyplot` interface and want to generate lots of figures without displaying them.

Each time you call your `rectify` function, you're making a new (very large!!) figure and then *keeping it in memory*.  `pyplot` keeps a reference to the figure so it can be displayed when you call `plt.show()`.  Either call `plt.close(fig)` or create the figures without using the `pyplot` state machine.  (`fig.clf()` will also work, but will keep references to a blank figures around.)

Also, given that you're reading in image files, your values are presumably on a regular x and y grid.  If so, use `imshow` instead of `pcolormesh`. It's much faster and more memory efficient.

---

As an example of the first issue, your `rectify` function basically does something like this, and you're presumably calling it repeatedly (as the loop below does):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rectify():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random((10,10)))
    fig.savefig('blah.png')

for _ in range(10):
    rectify()

plt.show()
```

Notice that we'll get 10 figures popping up.  `pyplot` holds on to a reference to the figure so that it can be displayed with `show`.

If you want to remove the figure from the `pyplot` state machine, call `plt.close(fig)`.

For example, no figures will be displayed if you do this: (each figure will be garbage collected as you'd expect after you remove the figure from pyplot's figure manager by calling `plt.close(fig)`.)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rectify():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random((10,10)))
    fig.savefig('blah.png')
    plt.close(fig)

for _ in range(10):
    rectify()

plt.show()
```

Alternately, you can bypass `pyplot` and make the figure and canvas directly.  Pyplot's figure manager won't be involved, and the figure instance will be garbage collected as you'd expect.  However, this method is rather verbose, and assumes you know a bit more about how matplotlib works behind-the-scenes:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas

# Don't need this, but just to demonstrate that `show()` has no effect...
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rectify():
    fig = Figure()
    FigureCanvas(fig)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random((10,10)))
    fig.savefig('blah.png')

for _ in range(10):
    rectify()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The memory still gets filled up making it all rather slow, but I didn't get the error this time. I thought about using imshow, but sadly my images aren't on a regular x,y grid...

Comment: Well, another approach would be to interpolate things onto a regular x,y, grid and then display with `imshow`.  It will probably take longer, but should be more memory efficient.  If what you have is working, though, it may not be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the needed memory if you clear the stored data in ax.
Add ax.clear() at the end of Joe Kington's rectify function. Then the program only need the memory of one pcolormesh.